# how to put a view on top of a MaterialTopTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native

I want to clone the profile page of an Instagram user. Still, I don't understand how to put all the information, the stories, the profile image, etc. on top of the bar navigator that allows you to navigate between posts, videos, and tags.

Any advice?

Thank you